# Connecting to SQL server via Java program

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, tcp

I am trying to connect to SQL server using Java program.It runs on port 1433 by default. While trying to run the program, I get SocketTimedOutexception.
So, I used this query to check if it's listening to tcp port and it's output is null.

```
SELECT local_tcp_port
FROM   sys.dm_exec_connections
WHERE  session_id = @@SPID
GO
```

Results in NULL.

Since I am trying to connect on Local host, I use went to SQL server configuration manager 
and ENABLED tcp/ip for MSSQLSERVER.(It was disabled by default) and then went to properties--> ip ddress and enabled IP12 since it was referring to 127.0.0.1 and restrted sql server.

Even now I am not able to connect to SQL server and it gives

```
java.net.SocketTimeOutException
```

Help me fix this.

Comment: What does your Java program look like? What errors are you getting when you try to use it? The typical problem with a local MS SQL Server configuration is that TCP/IP connection may not b enabled and port 1433 may not be specified explicitly.

Comment: Are you sure that `MSSQLSERVER` service is running/started? post your connection string (one you are using in Java code).

Comment: It got fixed on restarting the service again, Thanks